# How to click a button to open a customized menu (it's not context menu of the button) in android?

Tags: android

I hope to display a customized menu deleterecord.xml by clicking btnDelete button. It's not a context menu of btnDelete, opening a context menu need long click, so you can't use `registerForContextMenu` do it.

I have used openOptionsMenu() to open Options Menu while I click btnMore button, I hope to click btnDelete button to open another customized menu (The menu file is deleterecord.xml), how to do? Thanks!

```
 private void SetButtons() {       
    findViewById(R.id.btnMore).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openOptionsMenu();
        }
    });

   findViewById(R.id.btnDelete).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           //How to open deleterecord.xml menu
        }
    });
 }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_more, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {    

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.MoreShare:                
            return true;
        case R.id.MoreSettings:
            return true;
        case R.id.MoreAbout:               
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

**This is option menu menu_more.xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        tools:context="info.dodata.unlock.UnlockMain" >

        <item android:id="@+id/MoreShare"
           android:title="@string/MoreShare" />  

        <item android:id="@+id/MoreUninstall"
           android:title="@string/MoreUninstall" />    

        <item android:id="@+id/MoreAbout"
           android:title="@string/MoreAbout" /> 

    </menu>
```

**This is my customized menu deleterecord.xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@+id/ContextDeleteLess"
        android:title="Delete 10 records" />

    <item android:id="@+id/ContextDeleteMore"
        android:title="Delete 20 records"/>

</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a buttons onClick by android:onClick="methodName" in your xml layout under the button. This method should be in your views class and should have a single View argument. You can use this to determine if the view opens one menu or another. If it isn't a button view, make sure to set android:clickable="true".

Answer (score 0):

What is this other menu?Is it a Dialog with menu options?
However if you want to show Dialog with your options, you can do it like below:

findViewById(R.id.btnAnoter).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override

public void onClick(View v) {

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.menus);//This is your menu view.
dialog.show();
```

}

});

You need to store Menu reference in global variable and then inflate the menu again on button click.  Below is the code for the same:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Menu menu;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openMenu1();
        }
    });

    button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openMenu2();
        }
    });
}

private void openMenu1() {
    menu.clear();
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    openOptionsMenu();
}

private void openMenu2() {
    menu.clear();
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main1, menu);
    openOptionsMenu();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    this.menu = menu;
    menu.clear();
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Comment: The other menu is just like  Options Menu, I hope the UI of the other menu just like  Options Menu  which I click a button to display it

Comment: Would you please view my question? I have modified it and make it more clearly. Thanks!

Comment: Let me put my understanding.You have 2 buttons: "btn_more" and "btn_delete".You want to open two different option menus with different menu items on click of these two button??

Comment: Yes! I want to open two different option menus when I click  "btn_more" and "btn_delete"

Comment: I have test you code, it's OK if I click  button1 then click  button2 to open option menu, but the app crash if I click button2 first

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at ui.CleanupMain$1.onClick(CleanupMain.java:130)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

Comment: at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: I am not sure what you are doing wrong but in my sample application this is working fine in both the scenarios.

Comment: popup menu can do that, but it require API 11, my min API is 9 :(  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#options-menu

Answer (score 0):

You can create a menu layout and try opening it as popup.

```
findViewById(R.id.btnAnoter).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent popup=new Intent(getBaseContext(),Islemler.class);
    popup.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(popup);
  }
});
```

This is how I managed to create custom menu window.